# Checking if username is valid using jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery validation plugin to validate forms. I have a username field that I need validated. So far this is what I have:

```
$(".personal_form").validate({
        errorElement: 'div',
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 15,
                remote: {
                    url: "usernameChecker.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: {
                          username: function() {
                            return $( "#username" ).val();
                            },
                        },
                    },
            },

        },

        messages: {

            username: {
                required: "Please enter a username",
                maxlength: "Your username should not exceed 15 characters.",
                remote: "This username is taken."
            },

        },

        });
```

I want to make it so that if someone enters an invalid username it'll show an error. For example, if someone entered special characters : "!@#$%^&*()_+=~`-" it'll show an error. Valid usernames are usernames that have letters or numbers. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom validation rule that checks for the user name as per your rules like:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test(value);
    });
```

and add it with your validations

Comment: Works great! What if underscores were okay? How can I make it so underscores, letters, and numbers are valid?

Comment: Try this:

Change

[a-zA-Z0-9 ]  -->  [a-zA-Z0-9_ ]

it will allow space as well as under score.

Answer (score 0):

You can `pattern` attribute at `<input type="text">` element with `RegExp` `\w+|d\+` to match word or digit characters, `<label>` element, `css` `:focus`, `:invalid`, `:after`

```css
#username:focus:invalid + label[for="username"]:after {
  content: "input must contain only letters and numbers";
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" 
       pattern="\w+|d\+" 
       id="username"
       placeholder="input letters and numbers" />
<label for="username"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in :

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        var check = false;
        return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
    },
    "Please provide a valid username."
);

$(".personal_form").validate({
    errorElement: 'div',
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 15,
            regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/,
            remote: {
                url: "usernameChecker.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                      username: function() {
                        return $( "#username" ).val();
                        },
                    },
                },
        },

    },

    messages: {

        username: {
            required: "Please enter a username",
            maxlength: "Your username should not exceed 15 characters.",
            remote: "This username is taken."
        },

    },

});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `jQuery.validator.addMethod( name, method [, message ] )` for custom validation on form fields.

https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/